# How to name threads individually within a multiprocessing.dummy.Pool?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I want to name threads within a `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` so that I can view all their names when I call `threading.enumerate()` from the main thread. Is there a keyword I can apply when I call `pool.apply_async` to be able to name the threads? I would much rather name them upon creation than from within the `tester` function, just for cleanliness.

For example, if I have the sample code below:

```
import multiprocessing.dummy
from time import sleep
import threading

def tester():
    sleep(2)
    print("running \n")

def run_conc(number_of_threads, fxn):
    pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(processes=number_of_threads)
    for thread in range(number_of_threads):
        pool.apply_async(tester)
    print(threading.enumerate(), "\n")
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

run_conc(3, tester)
```

When I run it I receive the output:

```
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735632434048)>, <Thread(SockThread, started daemon 123145521917952)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-1, started daemon 123145527246848)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-2, started daemon 123145532502016)>, <DummyProcess(Thread-3, started daemon 123145537757184)>, <Thread(Thread-4, started daemon 123145543012352)>, <Thread(Thread-5, started daemon 123145548267520)>, <Thread(Thread-6, started daemon 123145553522688)>] 

running 
running 
running
```

I want to be able to name the 3 dummy threads in that list of threads so that I can identify which one is which. Or maybe there is a way to do this from within `concurrent.futures` that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The worker-threads within the pool are **not** created when you call `pool.apply_async` or other pool-methods, but already before when you instantiate the Pool. Calls to pool-methods use existing threads in the pool.

There is no way to name the threads upon initialization without manipulating the source. Your options are:

- renaming the worker-threads *after* the pool is ready instantiated
- monkey-patching pool internals to enforce a specific naming template

---

The first option is simple to implement, you just iterate over the `._pool`-attribute of the pool instance and change the `.name` of the contained threads:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(4)
    print([w.name for w in pool._pool])
    # ['Thread-1', 'Thread-2', 'Thread-3', 'Thread-4']

    for w in pool._pool:
        w.name = w.name.replace('Thread', 'ThreadPoolWorker')

    print([w.name for w in pool._pool])
    # ['ThreadPoolWorker-1', 'ThreadPoolWorker-2', 'ThreadPoolWorker-3', 'ThreadPoolWorker-4']

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Note I'm using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` here, just to comply with the example in the second option below since `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` is just a wrapper around `ThreadPool`.

---

For the second option, it would be possible to patch the factory-function for worker-threads `ThreadPool.Process` with a wrapper, extending the default name 'Thread-%d' (%d is filled with the value of a counter) with a more meaningful name like 'ThreadPoolWorker'.

```
# threadpool.py
# Module patching the name of worker-threads within ThreadPool

__all__ = ['ThreadPool']

from functools import wraps
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def rename_worker(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        w = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        w.name = w.name.replace('Thread', 'ThreadPoolWorker')
        return w
    return wrapper


ThreadPool.Process = staticmethod(rename_worker(ThreadPool.Process))
```

Usage:

```
from threadpool import ThreadPool as Pool


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(4)
    print([w.name for w in pool._pool])
    # ['ThreadPoolWorker-1', 'ThreadPoolWorker-2', 'ThreadPoolWorker-3', 'ThreadPoolWorker-4']
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found I can change the thread name from within the `tester` function by assigning a value to `threading.current_thread().name`. However, if anyone knows how to set the thread name upon creation from the `pool.apply_async` line that knowledge would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the thread name then following snippet would help

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,Queue
import threading

thread_names = Queue()
num_process = 4
for e in ['A','B','C','D']:
    thread_names.put('Thread-{}'.format(e))

def initializer(q):
    thread_name = q.get()
    threading.current_thread().name = thread_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(num_process=4,initializer=initializer,initargs=(threadnames,))
```

Comment: This is incorrect, see my answer above for a way to change the name of a thread after its creation. I'm still looking for a way to set the thread name at the time of creation, however.